# Need to read a register repeatedly using mmap(). Read value does not update. Do I need to remap?

Tags: linux, mmap, cpu-registers, beagleboneblack

EDIT: pasted wrong code

I am on a Beaglebone Black running TI's SDK linux, 4.14 I believe.

I think this is a pretty general question. you can probably jump to the next paragraph but if you care here are the specifics:
I am trying to monitor EPWMSS2's TBCNT register value. This is a counter. With the way it is configured, when the PWM is enabled the counter increments from 0 to some number, say 32000, and then starts again at 0. I want to store the current counter value I read, and then compare to the next value I read and check if the counter has reset to 0. `curr < last`

defines:

```
#define PWM2_OFFSET 0x48302000
#define PWM_SIZE 0x1000
#define TBCNT 0x8
```

I `mmap()` the registers I need and then every 100 usecs I print the register value. The printed value does not update, it is always the same:

```
int main(){
    volatile unsigned int *pwm_mmap;
    int16_t *count;
    int fd;
    int i;    

    fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "open: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }

    pwm_mmap = mmap(0, PWM_SIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, PWM2_OFFSET);
    if(pwm_mmap == MAP_FAILED) {
        fprintf(stderr, "mmap: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){

        *count = (void *)(pwm_mmap + TBCNT);
        printf("count = %d\n", *count);

        usleep(100);
    }

    if (munmap((void *)pwm_mmap, PWM_SIZE) < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "munmap: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }

}
```

so then I tried to `munmap()` and re-`mmap()` each time I printed the value. this worked, I got a new value the second time I mmapped. But I only get to do this twice, and then I get `mmap: cannot allocate memory`:

```
int main(){
    volatile unsigned int *pwm_mmap;
    int16_t *count;
    int fd;
    int i;  

    fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "open: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){

        pwm_mmap = mmap(0, PWM_SIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, PWM2_OFFSET);
        if(pwm_mmap == MAP_FAILED) {
            fprintf(stderr, "mmap: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        }

        *count = (void *)(pwm_mmap + TBCNT);
        printf("count = %d\n", *count);

        if (munmap((void *)pwm_mmap, PWM_SIZE) < 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "munmap: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        }

        usleep(100);
    }
}
```

what am I doing wrong? I am new to mmap and registers and really C in general. I'm sure I am abusing `mmap()` in some way. I would expect `munmap()` frees the memory used by `*pwm_mmap` so I am at a loss for why I am having memory allocation issues. Do I need to `malloc()` `pwm_map`?

thanks folks.

Comment: You call `mmap` twice with the size and offset values swapped???  Is this a copy-paste mistake?

Comment: Also, `*count = (void *)(pwm_mmap + TBCNT);` looks wrong because you are storing a pointer in an int, via a pointer `count` that has not been initialized.  I think perhaps you just mean `count = (int16_t *)(pwm_mmap + TBCNT);`

Comment: Yes that was a mistake.. thanks for pointing that out. I see now the assignment of count is incorrect. Thanks so much. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pointer that stores the `mmap()` return value doesn't need to use a `volatile` type because you're not using it directly to access memory mapped values.

The pointer that needs to use a `volatile` type is the pointer that is dereferenced to retrieve the memory mapped value: `count` in your case - it should be declared as:

```
volatile int16_t *count;
```

The purpose of `volatile` is to force a memory access every time and prevent the compiler from optimizing out the access and cache the value (e.g. in a register) when it thinks the value is unchanged.

Also, as already pointed out in one of the comments, the assignment to `count` seems to be wrong. What you probably want is:

```
count = (int16_t *)(pwm_mmap + TBCNT);
```

With your original assignment, you're writing the result of `pwm_mmap + TBCNT` to the memory location pointed to by `count`, which is an uninitialized pointer at that point. The behavior is undefined in that case, but likely to cause a segmentation fault.

Also pay attention to pointer arithmetic. Since `pwm_mmap` is a pointer to `unsigned int`, the address that results from `pwm_mmap + TBCNT` is the address returned by `mmap()` plus `TBCNT * sizeof(unsigned int)`, which is probably 32 (assuming a 32 bit platform). I'm not familiar with the platform you're working on, but make sure you're calculating the register offset correctly.

Having said that, there is no reason to remap every time. In fact, it would be inefficient to do so because (1) mmap/munmap are syscalls and that alone is a big overhead and (2) there is a lot of work going on in the kernel to do the actual mapping and unmapping.

Comment: Good spot with the `volatile`.  Another comment is that on some platforms, you may need to do something to tell the hardware not to cache that range of memory, if the OS or BIOS has not already set it up properly.  I don't know about this platform in particular.

Comment: Good point! The kernel can control whether pages are cached or not when it sets up the page tables. To control this from user space when `mmap()` is used with `/dev/mem`, uncached memory access can be specified with the `O_SYNC` flag to `open()`. In the absence of this flag, mapped pages are cached by default (unless they are in "high memory"). The relevant kernel code is in `uncached_access()` in `drivers/char/mem.c` (the driver for `/dev/mem`).